# Memory leak in FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

Update:

I think the leak is coming from `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(getLoaderId(), null, this);`
where i have my object implement LoaderCallback. Is there a way for me to clear the callback i tired setting it to

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(getLoaderId(), null, null);
```

but this crashes

Orig:

I have a list of objects in one of my fragments(A). When I navigate forward I add fragment A to the backstack.  After I have navigated to a new fragment and I dump the heap. I still see my object in the heap. When I get the shortest path in the dump it looks like below. I can see that in FragmentManagerImpl there is a reference to fragment A in mActive fragments which is keeping my lists object alive.

[image: memory leak]

Is my fragment supposed to stay in mActive fragments or is this a leak?

Adding to backstack

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
updateTransactionWith(info.getReplacement(), transaction, "replace");
transaction.addToBackStack(info.getReplacement().getClass().toString());
transaction.commit();
mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: What do you mean by you dump the heap? Maybe post the code that you think is de-allocating the memory.

Comment: Mean using the android device monitor to create a hprof file of the current heap. The list is a member of the fragment I thought it would de-allocate the object as I navigate away from the fragment

Comment: I don't think it does due to the fragment being added to the backstack. When you press back you probably want that fragment to be in the same state as when you left so you'll need all the objects as they were.

Comment: Probably, your Fragment keeps reference to Context, that's why you have memory leak

Answer (score 2):

By calling `addToBackStack()`, you're requesting the `FragmentManager` that the `Fragment` being replaced be just **stopped** and not **destroyed** because you're either anticipating that a back button press is very likely or, the `Fragment` is heavy on initialization and you would still like to avoid doing it again even though the user is not very likely to go back.

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) clearly state that

> If you do not call ***addToBackStack()*** when you perform a transaction
>   that removes a fragment, then that fragment is **destroyed** when the
>   transaction is committed and the user cannot navigate back to it.
>
> Whereas, if you do call ***addToBackStack()*** when removing a fragment,
>   then the fragment is **stopped** and will be **resumed** if the user navigates
>   back.

Hence, it's not a memory leak and your observations are quite in line with the expected behaviour.

However, just like an `Activity`, the system may still choose to **destroy** this `Fragment`, if it's running out of memory. But, that's expected behaviour too.

Comment: What about when i go back and pop it off the backstack and I still see this trace to my object. Shouldn't the fragment be destroyed after it is popped?

Comment: Say you have an Activity with Fragment F1 and you replace it with F2 along with a call to `addToBackStack()`. So, F1 is stopped but kept in memory. Now if you press back, the transaction is rolled back and F1 becomes your current fragment again. So, only F2 would get destroyed. If this isn't what you're observing, please explain the issue some more.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a memory leak.  You need to decide how to deal with your fragment's state.

Ideally you implement `onSaveInstanceState` and  `onViewStateRestored` saving your state to the bundle and restoring it from the bundle respectively.

Alternatively, if you're able to re-create your state easily, you may want to save the bother of (re)storing it using the bundle and just null your references in the `onPause` method and create them during the `onResume` method.  Be aware that `onResume` gets called even if the fragment has just been created, so be careful not to do that work more than once.

Either way, be sure to null your references to ensure your objects are marked for GC.

The FragmentManager will decide if it needs to discard and recreate the fragment as necessary in order to allow the user to go back to the fragment you added to the stack.  In conditions where there's very little else on the stack and/or there's lots of spare memory it will probably just keep a direct reference to the fragment you added to the back stack.

Given all that, you also need to be careful about keeping references to other fragments, activities, etc as that kind of state is difficult to recreate.

The following approach is recommended for providing proper back navigation:

```
// Works with either the framework FragmentManager or the
// support package FragmentManager (getSupportFragmentManager).
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                       // Add this transaction to the back stack
                       .addToBackStack()
                       .commit();
```

- More info:

  - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
  - http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html
- API docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: I also tried opening the fragment then press back and the hprof was the same it still had my fragment in the active stack. Should i not worry about this at all cause it is something android manages?

Comment: Can you post the code that adds the fragment to the back stack?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Updated my answer with an official snippet - the main difference being no string passed to addToBackStack().  I will create a sample project to see for myself tomorrow (need sleep) assuming you don't get a better response before then.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help so far! Can I ask the reason for removing the string from addToBackStack()?